# How to loop inside textbox in PHP

Tags: php, sql

How can I loop numbers inside a textbox whenever page is refresh? in PHP

```
<input type="text" name="name1" value="loophere">
```

I want a textbox automatically have a value number whenever  I refresh a page.
I need to used this for a column in my database and I want it automatically. I already have one column auto_increment in my database. Big thanks.

Comment: explain in brief way also put your code what you have try

Comment: I've tried nothing yet.

Comment: `loophere` means you need to display array values?

Comment: so explain in brief what you exactly want what is your expected output look like and many more

Comment: Yes sir @RamaLingam

Comment: What are you going to use this number for, exactly? Why does it need to be in a textbox? Do you understand that accepting user input here means the user can alter it?

Comment: @CodeCaster For the function UPDATE in sql. This is going to be my divider for all the rows I have. I already have one column which is already auto increment.

Comment: Start a session, then store the count in a session variable, `if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {  $_SESSION['count'] = 0; } else {  $_SESSION['count']++; }` then echo out your `$_SESSION['count']` where ever you wish to use it.

Comment: @dalelandry will try that out later. Thanks for another idea. And I don't even know why I have negative votes in here for this is very simple question.

Comment: @MonPadi yea the voting system in here can be tough when you get started in SO. What you could do is add some relevant back-end code that you have tried in order to increment the value of your target browsers refresh, `variable`. When you ask a question in SO, the ideal situation for one seeking to answer would be to copy paste some code you are working with or go to your _linked_ fiddle or other choice of online compiler and work with your code directly. This helps ***you*** get the answers you are looking for, more efficiently for all parties involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use `rand()`**

```
<input type="text" name="name1" value="<?php echo "1".rand();?>">
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

**OR Use `str_shuffle()`**

```
<?php
$string = "123456789AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnPpQqRrSsTtWwXxYyZz"; //You can use any string
$key_len = "5";
$string_shuffle = str_shuffle($string);
$session_key = str_shuffle(substr($string_shuffle, 3, $key_len));
?>
<input type="text" name="name1" value="<?php echo $session_key;?>">
```

Comment: That works too! Is there anyway I can start with number 1?

Comment: Just concat with "1" before `rand()`

Comment: I edited my post. Do you have any other suggestion besides this technique im gonna use?

Comment: And also how do you prevent it from repeating the same value?

Comment: Use `str_shuffle()`

Comment: Thank you brother! You just solved it lightning fast! Lmao. Dont know why I got negative votes while this is a very simple question. Till next time :)

Comment: Glad to help you!